# Can you use spread operator in the template in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Can you use spread operator in the template in angular?

I have seen [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301656/how-to-use-spread-operator-in-angular-component-template). The accepted answer says it is impossible to do so:

> It's unlikely that you're going to get this syntax to work in a
>   template (there are many valid typescript constructs that don't work
>   in templates).

But then I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050891/9953550) which suggests it is possible to do so.

When I try doing it I get an error.

> Unexpected token ., expected identifier, keyword, or string at column
>   2 in

I just want to set the record straight. Can you use spread operator in the template in angular? For example:

```
<div> [user]='{...member}'</div> 
<!--where member is an object-->
```

Comment: What Error do you get?

Comment: @nircraft I have updated the question with the error I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, and as can be seen in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2eushq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), the spread syntax doesn't appear to be allowed in Angular templates at the present time. A feature request has been opened in issue [11850](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11850) to support that syntax.